# faced error when i try to run GPU on Tensorflow within jupyter-notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gpu, jupyter, tensorflow2.0, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This code working fine and show gpu

import torch

## Get the number of available GPUs

num_gpus = torch.cuda.device_count()

if num_gpus > 0:
print(f"Number of available GPUs: {num_gpus}")

```
# Print the names of each GPU
for i in range(num_gpus):
    gpu_name = torch.cuda.get_device_name(i)
    print(f"GPU {i + 1}: {gpu_name}")
```

else:
print("No GPUs available.")

output of above code:Number of available GPUs: 1
GPU 1: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti

### I installed gpu using wsl but when i try to run any deep learning model i faced error

UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 24
21 model.summary()
23 # Train the model (you can adjust the number of epochs)
---> 24 model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
26 # Save the model (optional)
27 model.save('simple_model.h5')

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.**traceback**)
68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
71 finally:
72     del filtered_tb

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
51 try:
52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
56   if name is not None:

UnknownError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node sequential/dense_1/Sigmoid defined at (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main

File "", line 88, in _run_code

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 736, in start

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1922, in _run_once

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 516, in dispatch_queue

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 505, in process_one

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 412, in dispatch_shell

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 740, in execute_request

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 422, in do_execute

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 546, in run_cell

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3024, in run_cell

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3079, in _run_cell

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3284, in run_cell_async

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3466, in run_ast_nodes

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3526, in run_code

File "/tmp/ipykernel_23183/830650766.py", line 24, in

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1807, in fit

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1150, in train_step

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 590, in **call**

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py", line 1149, in **call**

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/sequential.py", line 398, in call

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py", line 515, in call

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py", line 672, in _run_internal_graph

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py", line 1149, in **call**

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/layers/core/dense.py", line 255, in call

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/activations.py", line 400, in sigmoid

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/backend.py", line 5915, in sigmoid

JIT compilation failed.
[[{{node sequential/dense_1/Sigmoid}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_814]

IF anyone have solution of this issue please share Thankyou.

### I installed gpu using wsl but when i try to run any deep learning model i faced error

UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 24
21 model.summary()
23 # Train the model (you can adjust the number of epochs)
---> 24 model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
26 # Save the model (optional)
27 model.save('simple_model.h5')

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.**traceback**)
68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
71 finally:
72     del filtered_tb

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
51 try:
52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
56   if name is not None:

UnknownError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node sequential/dense_1/Sigmoid defined at (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main

File "", line 88, in _run_code

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 736, in start

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1922, in _run_once

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 516, in dispatch_queue

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 505, in process_one

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 412, in dispatch_shell

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 740, in execute_request

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 422, in do_execute

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 546, in run_cell

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3024, in run_cell

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3079, in _run_cell

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3284, in run_cell_async

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3466, in run_ast_nodes

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3526, in run_code

File "/tmp/ipykernel_23183/830650766.py", line 24, in

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1807, in fit

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1150, in train_step

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 590, in **call**

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py", line 1149, in **call**

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/sequential.py", line 398, in call

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py", line 515, in call

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py", line 672, in _run_internal_graph

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py", line 1149, in **call**

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/layers/core/dense.py", line 255, in call

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/activations.py", line 400, in sigmoid

File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/backend.py", line 5915, in sigmoid

JIT compilation failed.
[[{{node sequential/dense_1/Sigmoid}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_814]

IF anyone have solution of this issue please share Thankyou.